# PayPal Account Types

Tags: spring-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am about to integrate PayPal module into my Spring MVC based application. Based on this link 
http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/current/PayPal-Environment-Setup.html seems like I need to create a PayPal business account. I assume this account is used by the merchant (the one who sell / has products). Which PayPal account should be used for the buyer, is it the personal account ? Can I test these two account types (including the transaction) on the sandbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do all of that.

http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/playing-in-paypals-sandbox-2880 gives you a high speed overview.

while https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/TR/tr_TR/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf is the official documentation.